# Get client ip address with nginx lua

Tags: nginx, lua

I have a lua script for nginx and would like to get the client's IP address.

Hovever

```
ngx.var.remote_addr is 10.0.2.2
```

in my case but if I check my ip address, it is 86.123.XXX.XXX

How can I get the 86.123.XXX.XXX address with nginx lua?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your current Nginx is behind a reverse proxy. You need to pass user IP through reverse proxy, something like this:

```
    location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://YOU_CURRENT_SERVER;
    }
```

After that, you can get user IP from header `X-Real-IP` or `X-Forwarded-For`, or `$http_x_real_ip`.